# Parsing JSON data in WordPress

Tags: javascript, json, wordpress

I want to get an Instagram user account info (follower, following and account name).

I used this endpoint:

`https://www.instagram.com/{username}/?__a=1`

When I add the `username` in the endpoint, it displays a JSON page that includes a lot of data such as follower, following and account name,

I use this code in WordPress for parsing the JSON code in `functions.php` and used a shortcode to a page.:

```js
function insta_shortcode_func() {
  $request = wp_remote_get('https://www.instagram.com/barkobco/?__a=1');

  if (is_wp_error($request)) {
    return false; // Bail early
  }

  $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body($request);

  $data = json_decode($body);

  return $data -> { 'count'};
}
add_shortcode('count_of_followers', 'insta_shortcode_func');
```

But nothing is displayed, I want to display follower, following and account name data.

Comment: You will probably have to debug this further yourself before stating a more specific question. Can you check if just executing the function 'echo insta_shortcode_func();' returns any data? The url seems to work fine at least. EDIT: Looking at the JSON it seems like there is no root property named count, you need to navigate the object properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return this to get the followers

```
return $data->graphql->user->edge_followed_by->count;
```

Here is the full code

```
function insta_shortcode_func()
{
    $request = wp_remote_get('https://www.instagram.com/barkobco/?__a=1');

    if (is_wp_error($request)) {
        return false; // Bail early
    }

    $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body($request);

    $data = json_decode($body);

    return $data->graphql->user->edge_followed_by->count;
}

add_shortcode('count_of_followers', 'insta_shortcode_func');
```

I think it will help you